# Passing vuejs input value to multiple data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to send an input value to more than one data. I searched but couldn't find it, how can I do it?
How can I do without method?

```
<input type="text" v-model="money_transfer.amount"/>

money_transfer: {
   amount: '', 
   source_amount: '', 
   target_amount: '', 
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax to pass input value to multiple variables:

```
<input
   :value="money_transfer.amount"
   @input="money_transfer.amount = money_transfer.source_amount = money_transfer.target_amount = $event.target.value"
>
```

Comment: The first one you wrote didn't work, but the 2nd one works.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad it helped you. I left only solution that works for you :)

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I misunderstood you at the beginning. I have edited my answer. Is everything ok now?